# Is there a way to determine the hash key attribute of a given AWS dynamodb table?

Tags: php, hash, amazon-web-services, attributes, key

Is there a way to determine the hash key attribute of a given AWS dynamodb table?

if there is a table TAB_A with the hash keys KEY_A, do we have a way to get "KEY_A" as the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the DescribeTable operation.

If you are using the AWS SDK for PHP, you can refer to the [API docs for DescribeTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_describeTable).

Here's an example of how you'd get the value:

```
// Run the DescribeTable command
$result = $dynamoDbClient->describeTable(array('TableName' => 'TAB_A'));

// Drill down into the results
$keys = $result->getPath('TableDescription/KeySchema/*/AttributeName');
print_r($keys);
#> Array ( [0] => 'KEY_A' )
```